# Как отправить на вебсокет сообщение из браузера?

Tags: javascript, websocket

У меня не получается отправить на вебсокет сообщение из браузера.
Беру пример с https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket, заменив только адрес сервера (поднят на ларавеле). После запуска сервер регистрирует connected с содержимым

```
{
"origin": "http://192.168.1.110",
"socketId": "837193062.631811439"
}
```

А сообщение "Меня зовут Джон" не регистрирует. И сообщения, которые должны транслироваться с сервера, до браузера не доходят. Сервер точно рабочий, клиент на ларавеле успешно с ним работает, подписывается на сообщения и получает их.

Везде пишут, что ПРОСТО поднимаешь соединение и оно ПРОСТО работает. Но у меня не получается. Что не так?

```
<script>
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.110:6001/app/local?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("[open] Соединение установлено");
    console.log("Отправляем данные на сервер");
    socket.send("Меня зовут Джон");
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(`[message] Данные получены с сервера: ${event.data}`);
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
    if (event.wasClean) {
        console.log(`[close] Соединение закрыто чисто, код=${event.code} причина=${event.reason}`);
    } else {
        // например, сервер убил процесс или сеть недоступна
        // обычно в этом случае event.code 1006
        console.log('[close] Соединение прервано');
    }
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log(`[error] ${error.message}`);
};
```

Comment: «подписывается на сообщения» — а где в вашем коде собственно эта самая подписка? Вы точно повторяете в своём коде правильное поведение, которое есть в клиенте на ларавеле?

Comment: А со стороны JS что пишет. Вот то "Соединение установлено" пишет ?

Comment: И сервер точно должен куда то вывести текст, который ему передают send. Может он его просто не выводит никуда

Comment: "а где в вашем коде собственно эта самая подписка?" Видимо её нет. Я не знаю, как её сделать. Кажется для подписки нужно как минимум суметь отправить сообщение (но я не уверен).

Comment: Со стороны js выводится: [open] Соединение установлено
Отправляем данные на сервер
[message] Данные получены с сервера: {"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{\"socket_id\":\"935463312.57132835\",\"activity_timeout\":30}"}

Comment: "И сервер точно должен куда то вывести текст" - не выводит. Как будто не присылали ничего.

Comment: Я как раз спрашиваю, а должен ли сервер выводить полученный текст. Может он его получает, но не выводит. Приведите часть кода сервера из которой следует, что он полученные сообщения куда то выводит

Comment: Затрудняюсь. Могу лишь сказать, что вижу сообщения, присланные извне пост запросами на вебсокет сервер, в консоли браузера-клиента и в админке сервера. У меня от этого всего уже уныние. Я не понимаю, как работают сокеты. Какая-то шайтан-машина. Лучше брошу это. Слишком сложно для меня.

Comment: А что отправляют те клиенты, от которых сообщения печатаются. Может там например надо в json отправить. Или например сервер вообще реагирует только на какие от определенные сообщения, а остальные просто игнорирует. Потому что ваш код сообщение отправляет и до сервера оно скорее всего доходит, вопрос только в том, что хочет видеть на входе сервер

Comment: В общем, что я сделал по итогу: Лара использует Laravel Echo, а тот базируется на Pusher. 
Для работы достаточно загрузить на страницу скрипт из https://js.pusher.com/4.3/pusher.min.js, только предварительно поменяв в нём параметры подключения с сервера пушера на свои рабочие (host, ws_port).